# SQL выборка значения строки по отсортированой колонке

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

### У меня задача отсортировать таблицу по колонке и получить номер строки по id.

Предположим у меня есть таблица с (n) количеством строк, каким способом мне будет лучше получить значения строки в отсортированной колонке.

Таблица:

idTable | name | result (FLOAT)

result - практически всегда уникальное значение.

Comment: Попробуйте через переменную. `SET @index=0; SELECT @index:=@index+1 AS index`. Хотя предположительно вы же будете эти записи потом получать и обрабатывать где-то. Может есть смысл там формировать порядковый номер?

Comment: Попробуйте сформулировать вопрос более понятным образом. Для справки: не принято говорить "отсортированная колонка" так как сортируются _строки_ на основании данных из какой нибудь колонки. А вообще в SQL сортировка делается единственным способом - заданием выражения ORDER BY

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, что нужно сделать, то ваша задача эквивалентна следующей: посчитать количество записей в таблице у которых поле `name` меньше или равно (в лексикографическом смысле) чем это поле у заданной записи. Тут должен сработать следующий запрос:

```
select count(*) where name <= (select name from MyTable where idTable = 12345)
```